# Doctrine2: eager loading relations similar to Eloquent ORM... can it be done?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I've used Eloquent ORM extensively. For the most-part it gets the job done but now I'm on a project that uses Doctrine2 and, while it does some things fantastically well, for other things I'm banging my head against a wall and no amount of Googling is getting me satisfaction.

With Eloquent, eager loading relationships can be handled like this:

```php
$articles = (new Article)->with('comments')->take(5)->get();
// SELECT * FROM articles LIMIT 5
// SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comments.articleId IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

The 2 sets of query results are matched together and I get the result I'm looking for.

The alternative method would be to eager load the results more lazily:

```
$articles = (new Article)->take(5)->get();
$articles->load('comments');
// Effectively this performs the same query execution
```

Now in Doctrine2 I'm struggling to find the analogue for this. I feel like I'm missing some secret magical incantation to get the same result.

The closest that I've come is to perform a query using a `LEFT JOIN`. This works for the most part *but*, because this is a one-to-many relationship, the multiple `comment` rows returned by the query will cause the `LIMIT` to return a truncated result of articles and comments.

```php
$builder = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->from('Article', 'article')
    ->leftJoin('article.comments', 'comments')
    ->select('article', 'comments');

// This is perfect... returns all the results expected
$results = $builder->getQuery()->getResult();
// This is less than perfect, it would return a broken result due to the LEFT JOIN in the query
$results = $builder->getQuery()->setMaxResults(5)->getResult();
```

Now this is where I'm stuck.

I suppose my question then is:

- How can I apply a `LIMIT` *and* eager load results?
- Alternatively, how can I lazily perform a eager load of associations?

Comment: Make one query to grab the first 5 article id's of interest.  Then do a second query with your joins.  With luck you might be able to nest the first query inside of the second though I have not always gotten that to work.

Comment: What do you mean with "broken result"? I think it should work with a `LEFT JOIN` and a `LIMIT`

Comment: @Cerad I agree that that is one way of doing it. The example I've given is a simplification of the query I'm working on that includes quite a few JOINs and is quite an expensive query. I've yet to implement something to test the real world impact of doing the query twice, once for retrieving the IDs and the second for the data.

@BramGerritsen I'll update the question to be clearer. It's broken because when you left join a one-to-many you will get duplicate rows which are still counted as results by an SQL `LIMIT`

Comment: Yep.  For my apps the overhead is not noticeable even with quite a few joins.  As far as real world impact goes, compare the performance between a working solution and a non-working solution.  Quite a difference.  Humor.